# Old PS/2 keyboard repeating letters

Tags: usb, keyboard, ps2, ps2-keyboard

I have an old PS/2 keyboard that I'm connecting to my Win10 computer via a PS/2-USB adapter. Problem is that it randomly decides to start repeating a given letter as though it's pressed. The only way to stop the repetition is to press some other key. But then the mouse (which I connect through wireless USB) buttons behave oddly (clicking on Chrome tabs causes them to close). To get the mouse back to normal I then have to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

I can't replicate this problem, it happens randomly.

I don't have any computers taking PS/2 input at home, so I can't test whether the keyboard itself is the problem, or if its the adapter.

Here is the brand of the keyboard:

[image].

There seems to be no evidence that this brand even exists online, but maybe it's because I couldn't type in the Korean characters.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning it? Crumbs under the keys?

Comment: I have an old PS/2 keyboard with similar behaviour, and in my case it's the keyboard (broken conductor lines). Chances to repair it are slim (I tried with mine, and didn't succeed).

Comment: @DavidPostill There are some crumbs and a few short hairs under the keys. How do I get them out? I tried vacuum cleaner, but some are still left.

Comment: You can get small vacuum cleaners. Or use a small brush. I use a makeup brush - like this one https://assets.thebodyshop.com/medias/fan-brush-1-640x640.jpg?context=product-images/h8a/hfa/9023053955102/fan-brush_1-640x640.jpg

Comment: There are compressed air cans as well to blow out the crap ...

Comment: Also, most key caps pop off easily, e.g. using a piece of heavy thread or small screwdriver. Do only a few at a time... and the larger keys may not be worth removing.